# Compare file against db table without primary key

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have flat files...which has pipe separated values...
Also we have corresponding tables for each of these files.

Table/file dont have any unique/primary column.

To compare the data, we converting file to data table (c#,.net)

Take first row in DB_Datatable...
 Compare it against each row in file_DataTable

If we could not find match in file_dataTable ...we will consider as different.

In this case, if both tables match...and if each tables have 10 records...there would be 100 row comparisons.

This logic works, but for files > 20K, it is taking huge time.

Could someone suggest me a better approach?

Note : Can we make a hash for each row(using content of each row)...and sort based on it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataRowComparer<TRow>` and a `Dictionary` for this.

Sample usage (not comparing two data tables, but, this should get you started):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Foo", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Bar", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add("Test", 1);
dt.Rows.Add("Test", 2);
dt.Rows.Add("Testing",1);
dt.Rows.Add("Testing",1);
var dictionary = new Dictionary<DataRow, int>(DataRowComparer<DataRow>.Default);
foreach(var row in dt.AsEnumerable())
{
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(row)) dictionary[row] = 1;
    else dictionary[row]++;
}
```

Output is as expected: it shows 3 items, third item ("Testing", 1) has a 2 for the value.

Alternately, you can use a `HashSet` with the same custom comparer. Lookups should at least be O(1) instead of O(n)

Either way, the complexity should decrease from O(n1 * n2) to O(n)

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Foo", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Bar", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add("Test", 1);
dt.Rows.Add("Test", 2);
dt.Rows.Add("Testing",1);
dt.Rows.Add("Testing",1);
var hash = new HashSet<DataRow>(DataRowComparer<DataRow>.Default);
foreach(var row in dt.AsEnumerable())
{
    if (hash.Contains(row)) Console.WriteLine("Already in data set");
    hash.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: I do not see any performance improvement in this code. It is just that you are using a different class to compare.